# how to remove broken application from application menu?

Tags: applications

[image][image]

I installed it from elementary blog and it didn't worked so i deleted repository and build folders but this icon stayed here. I JUST WANT TO KNOW HOW TO PROPERLY REMOVE THIS ?  so that it will save space and want to remove this icon too !

as you said i went to the location but its not letting me delete the file !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know the app. If you cannot remove the app in software center or via `sudo apt-get remove <feedreader>` you have to remove the files manually.

Next is just for the icon / entry in application menu:

Probably you have a feedreader.desktop file either in `/usr/share/applications` or in `~/.local/share/applications`.

If you delete the file(s) the entry will disappear.

If you want to delete the icon from disk, you should open the feedreader.deskop file. There you will find a line `Icon=/path/to/icon`. Delete the icon file. **I would not recommend to delete the icon** because it seems to be a universal used icon for RSS programs.

Comment: Thank you friend . I don't know weather i removed whole file and repository from my system or not. But thank you for the help . I removed the file from Terminal . now the icon is no longer issue.